# Angular + Azure DevOps(TFS): replace tokens in environment.ts file, environment agnostic angular build

Tags: angular, tfs, deployment, build, azure-devops

Let's say we have a tokenised `environment.ts` file like:

```
export const environment = {
  production: #{production}#
}
```

where `production` type must be `boolean`.

Now, we want to `ng build` so we get an environment agnostic build, which we can deploy to any environment. When deploying to a specific environment we just replace tokens in `main.js` or `main.*.js` (that's where the `environment.ts` file is bundled).

The problem is, that `ng build` fails as the above `environment.ts` has compile tyme errors.

Is there any way how to achieve that? How to produce an environment agnostic angular app build which can be deployed to any environment with any configuration?

PS: this [task](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme) is used for replacing tokens

Comment: I'm not happy with replacing tokens in bundled files, but I really didn't find any other solution. One could suggest to move configuration to `ConfigService` etc., but thats different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have come up so far:

```
export const environment = {
   production: !!'#{production}#',
}
```

When VSTS variable `production` is not empty then `!!'#{production}#'` is resolved to `true`, otherwise to `false`.

Because VSTS does ignore variables with empty string (`""`) value.
It is important to set the `production` variable for falsy value as:

[image]

according to task settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution to make your file still compile while using replace token task would be:

```
export const environment = {
  production: '#{production}#' === 'true'
}
```

In your pipeline set variable `production` to value `false` when not in production (or any value to avoid the task warning you of a undefined variable) and `true` when in production.